# Android SurfaceView bug

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have encountered the nasty Android SurfaceView behavior:
When you leave an Activity with SurfaceView and quickly go back, the previous content of SurfaceView doesn't disappear and is displayed under the new one.

See the example project that reproduces the problem, please.
https://github.com/t-artikov/surface-view-bug

I have found that this is an Android bug, which was fixed on Android P
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72624889
But I need to get it to work on earlier OS versions.

Will be glad to any ideas how to solve the issue. Maybe someone has already encountered it and knows a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This problem wouldn't occur on an API 22 device. I used the Pixel 2 API 26, as the OP did, in order to reproduce it.

It appears that, under this condition, the `SurfaceView` saves its current contents to some sort of hidden intermediate surface, at certain times (like when a transition begins). The condition can't be corrected by replacing the `SurfaceView`, or by adjusting the background drawables of any ancestor views.

Your `onDrawFrame()` is clearing the buffer with a transparent color, which is letting this "intermediate surface" show through. If you don't need the transparency, you could just clear it to solid white:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

**EDIT**

I found myself coming back to this question, as it is a very troublesome bug. Since you need to keep the transparency, it turns out you can add this to `SecondActivity`, to avoid the problem:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    super.onStart();
}
```

I also tried disabling hardware acceleration, but no luck there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I did not mention, but, yes, the surface need to be transparent, because the rest Activity content should be visible under it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does not seem to work(. In the test example, the problem became much less reproducible (but still possible - manually or by decreasing the back delay to 50ms). In a real application, I can catch the bug as easily as before (I believe, because Activities are heavier and even without animation, there is a time interval while one stops and the other starts).

Comment: Hmmm I cannot reproduce it even a single time, but it's possible my suggestion to put it in `onStart()` is bad (from a timing perspective). What if you put a `((Activity)getContext()).overridePendingTransition(0,0)` immediately after the call to `startActivity()`?

Comment: Have tried it, as well as ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, 0, 0) as the second parameter of startActivity. No changes unfortunately.

Comment: One more case of the bug: while the application is running, open the recent application list and quickly return to the application by selecting it.
This can be done automated through "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH; adb shell input tap 500 500".

Comment: Ah, I am indeed able to reproduce it with the adb command. Would you like another workaround? Try calling `mGLView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE )` in `onPause()` (order doesn't seem to be too important), and undo that change in `onResume()`.

Comment: Yeh, already tried this. This fixes the bug, but makes the contents of SurfaceView invisible during screen transitions and in the recent apps preview. Unacceptable in my case. Hide SurfaceView later than Activity.onPause is too late - it does not remove the intermediate surface.

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @KasperFinneNielsen None besides those listed.